# How are Pokeballs passed down from the parents when breeding?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I plan on breeding two pokemon (one in a timer ball and one in a pokeball) and I want the pokemon to be in a normal Pokeball. Which one will it get?

Comment: If you're looking for how it works in Sun & Moon now, you can find that inf [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/293798/118783).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**For *Female* - *Male* breeding (standard):**

- The Pokeball the child inherits will be of the Female's Pokeball

**For *Female* - *Ditto* breeding (no Male to breed with):**

- The Pokeball the child inherits will be of the Female's Pokeball

**For *Male* - *Ditto* breeding (no Female to breed with):**

- The Pokeball the child inherits will be a Pokeball, regardless of what Pokeball Ditto is in

**For *Ungendered* - *Ditto* Breeding (breeding Rotom, Unown, etc.)**

- The Pokeball the child inherits will be a Pokeball, regardless of what Pokeball Ditto is in

Comment: Ditto don't breed with Ditto. (Yes, really)

Comment: That's why I had no clue what it was, thanks for the fix

Comment: The third bullet is wrong. I have bred several Pokemon with my Quick Ball Ditto and all the children are in Pokeballs.

Comment: "The Pokeball the child inherits will be of the Female's Pokeball", but this won't work with Cherish Ball and Master Ball, the child will inherit a Pokeball anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Well now in X & Y, it is the ball that the mother was in. So if the female of the two breeding is in the timer ball the baby pokemon will also be in a timer ball.

"With breeding in the past, whenever you had an egg, the Pokémon that hatched from it would always be within a standard Poké Ball. However, as of Pokémon X & Y, this all changes. From now on, the Poké Ball the egg hatches in is now solely based upon the ball that the mother was caught in. So, if you're breeding a female Pokémon you caught in a Dusk Ball with a male Pokémon in a Cherish Ball, the baby will always be inside the Dusk Ball. This won't work with the Master Ball, however."

Source:[Serebii](http://www.serebii.net/xy/breeding.shtml)

Comment: Dang. That means I have to keep searching for a Nidoran with Hustle

Comment: @ShadowZorgon  I edited with quote and source if you wanted further proof. :)  And why do you just want the regular Pokeball?  I personally like the look of the timer ball anyway.

Comment: In fact, the best Pokeball to use in breeding would be the Luxury ball, as it doubles the happiness earned for any Pokemon.  This means that you can avoid the absurd costs for those Pokeballs and afford to have them on ever baby Pokemon you breed.

Comment: @Retrosaur - with Soothe Bell & Befriending o-power I've never had a need for luxury balls

Comment: @fogolicious I prefer to keep my team to one PokeBall unless there is a specific or one I can not easily change. My Nidoqueen was the only one w/out it. The only one w/out a normal PokeBall is my Shiny Spiritomb, who is in a Dusk Ball.